# Gurobi Java - Stop the optimization when lower bound is higher than a particular known value

Tags: callback, gurobi, lower-bound

I am solving multiple CVRP s using Gurobi Callback in JAVA. However, for a particular CVRP problem, when the best bound (lower bound) after 60 seconds is higher than the optimal solution of another CVRP already evaluated, I do not need to continue the optimization. How do I stop the optimization when the current lower bound is higher than a particular value?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set the TimeLimit parameter to 60 seconds. When your call to `GRBModel.optimize()` is finished, check the values of the Status, Obj and ObjBound attributes. If your solution value is not what you want, call `GRBModel.optimize()` again to continue solving.